# Unable to connect IoT Development Kit to AWS cloud Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, iot

I have a marvell iot kit (mw302)which contains various sensors whose data needs to be uploaded on the AWS cloud. I have followed the steps given in this link https://github.com/DewMobility/IoT-Marvell/wiki. A the last step instead of uploading data it gives me an error "aws shadow connect failed : -3  " . I have already tried 2 different flash files both gives the same error. Googling the error results to nothing.